# UITabbar also change the tab with extra UIButton [hell] swift 4

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

New to swift 4 programming need help in UIButton.

There are two buttons for appointments, one on tabbar and other is UIButton.
How can i program that UIButton to navigate to “Appointments UIView on UITabbar” without disappearing the tabbar when navigating?

Comment: Please can you take your time to make the question clearer, and maybe show us what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you well, but if I'm right you want to access a specific tab by touching a UIButton, not the UITabBarController.

Solution for this is adding an action to your button like below:

```
@IBAction func goToAppointments(sender: AnyObject) {
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = x
}
```

Where `x` is an integer with the position of "Appointments Tab" in tab bar.